# Google Adsense Advertisements Not Displaying

Tags: wordpress, adsense

Two days I inserted Google Adsense ads on a number pages for a client's WordPress site.

Yet, the ads are not displaying at all. Instead I see white space. How can I get the ads to display?

Here's more details about the steps I took:

- I logged into the client's Google Adsense account to copy the Google Adsense code and then hard coded it into the website, just to test.
- I installed the Google Publisher Toolbar Chrome plugin and went to https://metiza.com/category/healthy-me/ to confirm the ad code has been inserted.
- When I log into the client's Google Adsense account and click on "Home" in the menu, there is a green checkmark next to "You're successfully created an ad unit" text. However they is NOT a green checkmark next to "Place the ad code on MyWebsiteHere".
- As you can see the website is SSL (uses "https"). Could that be a problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, have you solved your problem? It's very actual to me.

Comment: I figured it out. The reason why Google Adsense ads were originally not appearing on pages like https://metiza.com/category/healthy-me/ is because these pages show blog post categories.


When adding Google Adsense code successfully to https://metiza.com/ I had to only add them to single blog post pages or the home page (https://metiza.com/) and follow these steps for inserting responsive Google Adsense code:

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124?hl=en&ref_topic=1307438


If this works for you please mark my answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on AdSense forum and this is the answer:

> After you add the code AdSense performs a second review of the site and it's contents. Until that is completed and you receive another email, no ads would show. The second review can take anywhere from a few days (ie: 3 days) to several weeks, and sometimes as long as a month.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?#!msg/adsense/S2aUzRAx9kM/i39TB6DOEQAJ

Comment: Slava, please post if you are successful in adding Google AdSense code onto your website. Good luck!

Comment: Hi :-) Still no luck, sorry. I'm still waiting for this time :-D But I will report if I'm successful / unsuccessful with it within 2 weeks.

Comment: Slava can you please post the URL where you are having problems with adding Google AdSense code? That way I can see if you have breaking any of Google's rules that would prevent you from adding Google AdSense code on your website.

Comment: Slava,

I think I know why http://show-me-how.ru/ isn't displaying Google Ads.

First, remove all Google ads from your website except your home page (http://show-me-how.ru/). 

Google doesn't like it when you have ads on category pages (like http://show-me-how.ru/category/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8/).

Resubmit your Google Adsense for the home page only. Then, after your Google Adsense ad appears on your home page you should be able to insert ads on single posts, but not category pages. I ran into this exact some problem.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: @risingPhoenix1979 heh, thank you very much. I applied your recommendations and, I think, it's been a lot of time since you told me it.

The ad is only on the main page and nowhere else. But it's still not working :-/
http://show-me-how.ru/

Comment: Slava, hopefully your Google Adsense add will appear on your home page. Give it a weeks and then let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that Slava.

Comment: Ow, yep, nothing bad :) Perhaps, you wondered, that there's even no room for ads - we, finally, just decided to remove ads at all, since it's not displayable any way. Thank you for all your help! :)